# UVa 11450 in python - dp

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I struggle with task from UVa Online Judge
[11450 - Wedding shopping](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2445&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2021609610).

I have managed to code it in C++ and get AC.
Unfortunately, I cannot do the same in python - TLE.

I would like to learn to code in python, that's why I am using it. I know that C++ is significantly faster and better for competitive programming etc.

Any ideas what's wrong with this code ? How can I improve it go get AC?

```
from sys import stdin, stdout


def shop(money, curr_g):
    if money < 0:
        return -1
    if curr_g == c:
        return m - money
    if memo[money][curr_g] is not -1:
        return memo[money][curr_g]
    ans = -1
    for model in range(1, price[curr_g][0] + 1):
        ans = max(ans, shop(money - price[curr_g][model], curr_g + 1))
    memo[money][curr_g] = ans
    return ans


price = list(list() for i in range(21))
memo = list(list(-1 for j in range(21)) for i in range(201))
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    m, c = map(int, stdin.readline().split())
    for a in range(c):
        price[a] = [int(x) for x in stdin.readline().split()]

    for a in range(201):
        for b in range(21):
            memo[a][b] = -1

    ans = shop(m, 0)
    stdout.write(str(ans) + "\n") if ans >= 0 else stdout.write('no solution\n')
```

Comment: I don't know UVa, but, unless it's a crap system, which seems unlikely, your problem is almost certainly that you're using the wrong algorithm. Any online judging system that accepts code in languages like Python is going to design their problems so that the right algorithm is fast enough even if you use Python, but the wrong algorithm is too slow even if you implement it in tightly optimized C.

Comment: So, while there definitely are things you can do to speed a few things up by a constant factor (e.g., use a list comprehension instead of passing a generator comprehension to `list`, don't build `memo` as a list of lists of 420 `-1`s just to reassign them all to `-1` later, etc.), those probably aren't relevant here.

Comment: As a side note, that `is not -1` test is incorrect, even though you probably get away with it. In Python, `is` tests for two objects being the same object. That will happen to be true for two separate copies of `-1` in a default build of CPython, both because it caches small integers, and because it folds literal constants in a module, but that's not at all guaranteed by the language. If you want to test equality, use `==` and `!=`, not `is` and `is not`.